# How to show the current location from another location in google maps App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I integrated google maps in my app. I have to show map from current location to destination. In my app, It's working fine. I had taken a subview on the top of map view. Inside the view I have a button, If i am clicking on the button. I am navigating to google maps app. But it's showing only current location. It's not showing the destination.

Here is my code...

```
- (IBAction)onMapNavigationButtonClick:(id)sender {
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *anURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?pickupLat=%f&pickupLng=%f&dropLat=%f&dropLng=%f",self.a2bBooking.pickupLocation.latitude,self.a2bBooking.pickupLocation.longitude ,self.selectedDestinationZone.latitude.doubleValue,self.selectedDestinationZone.longitude.doubleValue];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anURLString]];
}
```

If anyone having idea about this.Please help me out..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Google has a [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) API and you can use it to open an app in directions or navigation mode. Have a look at aforementioned documentation for further details.

Your code should be changed to something similar to

```
- (IBAction)onMapNavigationButtonClick:(id)sender {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *anURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&travelmode=driving",self.a2bBooking.pickupLocation.latitude,self.a2bBooking.pickupLocation.longitude ,self.selectedDestinationZone.latitude.doubleValue,self.selectedDestinationZone.longitude.doubleValue];
    [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anURLString]];
}
```

I hope this helps!